# how to keep file format when using sed editor?

Tags: bash, shell

suppose a file that contains:

```
a=1234
b=5678
c=word
```

i am writing a bash script that will change a's value. i use following command:

```
echo `sed "s/\(a=\).*/\1 new/" file` >file
```

it gives:

```
a=new b=5678 c=word
```

i also tried following (using anchors) still getting same format:

```
echo `sed "s/\(a=\).*[\n]$/\1 new/" file` >file
echo `sed "s/\(a=\).*'\n'$/\1 new/" file` >file
```

where i want:

```
a=new
b=5678
c=word
```

how to do that?

Comment: Drop the `echo` and quotes. And don't overwrite input file with output file - use `-i` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-i` argument to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i 's/\(a=\).*/\1new/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could a following sed too once.

```
sed  -i '/^a=/s/=.*/=new/g'   Input_file
```